# How to run linux containers in windows server 2016 in aws cloud vm

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-swarm-mode

I am not able to run linux containers in windows server 2016 in AWS cloud.
How to run linux containers in windows server 2016 which requires docker ee version

Comment: Any error message? Hyper-V has to be activated if you use Docker on Windows.

Comment: i  some how was able to activate Hyper-V and pull linux images, but not able to start/run a linux container on these linux images.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What commands do you use? Error messages? It is difficult to help without it.

Comment: i followed this url                              https://blog.himorpheus.com/2018/02/12/running-linux-containers-on-windows-server-2016/                                                                                                                and when do Restart-Service docker

Comment: when i do Restart-Service docker i got following errors                                                ReStart-Service : Failed to start service 'docker (Docker)'.
At line:1 char:1
+ ReStart-Service docker
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Restart-Service]
   , ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartServiceCommand in aws cloud windows server 2016